# How do I determine the data source of a Java / hibernate dropdown

Tags: java, hibernate

OK, I suspect this is going to rate as one of the stupidest questions ever, but here goes:

I am a .Net and PHP developer, with no knowledge of Java at all, but have nevertheless been asked to take a look at a legacy Java application (which, of course, has no documentation).

There are a few tasks, but I'm stuck already on a simple one - I need to change the entries in a dropdown, which pulls the list from a database. I thought I had identified the correct DB table, but changing it has no effect on the dropdown. As there are hundreds of tables in the DB, with unhelpful names, tracking down the right one would be time-consuming, so I've turned to the code to work out the right table.

Here is the jsp that generates the dropdown:

```
<td class="labelCell"><span style="COLOR: red">*</span>Query Status:</td>
<td>
  <select class="inputBox" id="queryStatus" name="queryStatus">
    <c:if test="${queryStatusList != null}">    
      <c:forEach items="${ queryStatusList }" var="statusList">
        <c:set var="statusIdValue" value="${statusList.lookupId}"/>    
        <c:set var="statusNameValue" value="${statusList.description}"/>
        <option value="<c:out value="${statusIdValue}"/>"
        <c:if test="${statusIdValue == command.queryStatus}">
          <c:set var="queryStatus" value="${statusNameValue}"/> SELECTED
        </c:if>
        >
        <c:out value="${statusNameValue}"/></option>
      </c:forEach>
    </c:if>
  </select>
</td>
```

I can see that it iterates through queryStatusList, putting each entry into an option tag.

What I can't see is where queryStatusList is populated from - 'queryStatusList' doesn't appear anywhere else in the source.

All i need to know is where to look to find the query that populates queryStatusList. Can someone help?

Comment: Its a complex answer. First of all, search "queryStatusList" in ".java" files. (ctrl + H in eclipse -> File search -> Containing text="queryStatusList", File name patterns = "*.java" -> Search [all fields without quotes])

The project uses any MVC framework? (Like struts, spring MVC, etc... no hibernate).

Comment: @Nullpo, that should be an answer...

Comment: @Nullpo - thanks for your reply - unfortunately, the only occurrences of queryStatusList are the ones in the snippet above. I don't have any .java files, only .jsp.
I believe that it's using the spring framework, and possibly Hibernate as well

Comment: orry... but if in the project, the word "queryStatusList" is not in another file... and without the entire code, it is very complicated to help you.... You can copy here the web.xml file? Maybe with that, we can see which controller/view framework its used in that project :)